# Bluetooth: Unable to connect internet on laptop from Nokia N73

Tags: ubuntu, internet, bluetooth

Earlier I had been doing Internet on laptop after connecting my Nokia N73 to laptop via bluetooth. But I'm not clear as to what happened a day that after that time I couldn't connect via bluetooth.

Earlier to enable Internet on my laptop I didn't follow any document. I simply got my laptop connected to the cell phone via bluetooth and selected the option on laptop for connecting Internet.

Now when there seems to be a problem & many days have passed since I'm unable to connect to Internet via bluetooth, I followed [this document](http://www.learnosity.com/techblog/2006/12/vodafone-nokia-n73-bluetooth-modem-with-ubuntu-linux-howto/). But still I couldn't get it work.

Please look at the below files on my laptop which are prepared following the document. (I have included the bluetooth address of the device)

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/etc/bluetooth$ cat rfcomm.conf
rfcomm0 {
# # Automatically bind the device at startup
bind yes;
#
# # Bluetooth address of the device
device 00:1B:EE:95:BB:09;
#
# # RFCOMM channel for the connection
channel 2;
#
# # Description of the connection
comment "Nokia N73";

rfcomm release 0 # make sure is it not already connected
rfcomm connect 0 # create a connection to rfcomm device 0
}
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/etc/bluetooth$
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/etc/bluetooth$ cd /etc/ppp/peers
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/etc/ppp/peers$ ls
provider  vodafone
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/etc/ppp/peers$ cat vodafone
# from www.hingston.demon.co.uk/mike/nokia6680.html 
 noauth
#change this if you move the path to your connect script
  connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/vodafone-connect"
#change this if you move the path to your disconnect script
  disconnect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/vodafone-disconnect"
#I found that I needed this to remove problems with loopback on connecting
  silent
#remove this if you don't want lots of information going to /var/log/messages
  debug
#this is the device specified in your rfcomm.conf file
  dfdf
#speed at which to connect - might be worth trying higher...
# 115200
#this is needed so that a default route is added to your routing table
  defaultroute
#this is needed so that you pick up Orange's DNS settings
  usepeerdns
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/etc/ppp/peers$
```

The below files are exactly the same as in the link.

```
/etc/chatscripts/vodafone-connect
/etc/chatscripts/vodafone-disconnect
```

I feel much comfortable to use bluetooth for Internet and also its more speed than using a cable.